# El siguiente código no me funciona cuando intento insertar datos

Tags: javascript

```js
function iniciar(){
 cajadatos=document.getElementById('cajadatos');
 var boton=document.getElementById('grabar');
 boton.addEventListener('click', agregarobjeto, false);
 if('webkitIndexedDB' in window){
  window.indexedDB=window.webkitIndexedDB;
  window.IDBTransaction=window.webkitIDBTransaction;
  window.IDBKeyRange=window.webkitIDBKeyRange;
  window.IDBCursor=window.webkitIDBCursor;
 }else if('mozIndexedDB' in window){
  window.indexedDB=window.mozIndexedDB;
  }
 var solicitud=indexedDB.open('mibase');
 solicitud.addEventListener('error', errores, false);
 solicitud.addEventListener('success', crear, false);
}
function errores(e){
 alert('Error: '+e.code+' '+e.message);
} 
function crear(e){
 bd=e.result || e.target.result;
 if(bd.version==''){
  var solicitud=bd.setVersion('1.0');
  solicitud.addEventListener('error', errores, false);
  solicitud.addEventListener('success', crearbd, false);
 }else {
  mostrar();
  }
}
function crearbd(){
 var almacen=bd.createObjectStore('peliculas',{keyPath:'id'});
 almacen.createIndex('BuscarFecha', 'fecha',{unique: false});
}
function agregarobjeto(){
 var clave=document.getElementById('clave').value;
 var titulo=document.getElementById('texto').value;
 var fecha=document.getElementById('fecha').value;
 var transaccion=bd.transaction(['peliculas'], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
 var almacen=transaccion.objectStore('peliculas');
 var solicitud=almacen.add({id: clave, nombre: titulo, fecha: fecha});
 solicitud.addEventListener('error', errores, false);
 solicitud.addEventListener('success', mostrar, false);
 document.getElementById('clave').value='';
 document.getElementById('texto').value='';
 document.getElementById('fecha').value='';
}
function mostrar(){
 cajadatos.innerHTML='';
 var transaccion=bd.transaction(['peliculas']);
 var almacen=transaccion.objectStore('peliculas');
 
 var indice=almacen.index('BuscarFecha');
 var cursor=indice.openCursor(null, IDBCursor.PREV);
 cursor.addEventListener('error', errores, false);
 cursor.addEventListener('success', mostrarlista, false);
} 
function mostrarlista(e){
 var cursor=e.result || e.target.result;
 if(cursor){
  cajadatos.innerHTML+='<div>'+cursor.value.id+' - '+cursor.value.nombre+' - '+cursor.value.fecha+'<button onclick="eliminar(\''+cursor.value.id+'\')">Eliminar</button></div>';
  cursor.continue();
 }
}
function eliminar(clave){
 if(confirm('Está Seguro?')){
  var transaccion=bd.transaction(['peliculas'], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
  var almacen=transaccion.objectStore('peliculas');
  var solicitud=almacen.delete(clave);
  solicitud.addEventListener('error', errores, false);
  solicitud.addEventListener('success', mostrar, false);
 }
}
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <title>IndexedDB API</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexed.css">
  <script src="indexed.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <section id="cajaformulario">
   <form name="formulario">
    <p>Clave:<br><input type="text" name="clave" id="clave"></p>
    <p>T&iacute;tulo:<br><input type="text" name="texto" id="texto"></p>
    <p>A&ntilde;o:<br><input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha"></p>
    <p><input type="button" name="grabar" id="grabar" value="Grabar"></p>
   </form>
  </section>
  <section id="cajadatos">
   No hay informaci&oacute;n disponible
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor agrega tu html para tener un [mcve]

Comment: y que error te da??

Comment: Simplemente no realiza ninguna accion cuando intento grabar los datos con el boton "grabar"

Comment: Soy novísimo en esto (vengo de VBA-Excel que era un mundo civilizado y ahora me siento en la jungla)... pero veo que de estas dos opciones: if('webkitIndexedDB' in window){... if('mozIndexedDB' in window){… En mi caso, no es ninguna !!! No soy capaz de ver en que año estamos. Pero si al final lo resolviste: CUÉNTANOSLO.

Answer (score 0):

Soy un poco novato en esto del `Javascript`, pero creo que el error puede estar en que inicias está línea:

```
boton.addEventListener('click', agregarobjeto, false);
```

Antes de que la función **crear(e)** se inicie, en cuyo caso sería poner esa línea al final de la función iniciar.

Ya me dirás si te ha funcionado

¡Animo!

Comment: No amigo, no me funciona